# gitlab behind https terminating reverse proxy and oauth

Tags: github, oauth, https, reverse-proxy, gitlab

I have installed GitLab 7.8.4 on a server behind pound which terminates HTTPS connections for me.

How do I configure GitLab to always assume that it is accessed via HTTPS without letting it also handle the HTTPS connection?

In practice I see the following problem:

I'm adding GitHub authentication to my GitLab instance and try to log into GitLab using my GitHub account. This works fine as long as everything is over HTTP. But if I use the HTTPS address to my GitLab instance, then the authentication with GitHub will fail.

The problem seems to be that GitLab passes the HTTP address to GitHub like this:

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[...]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgitlab.myurl.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&state=[...]&scope=user%3Aemail
```

And then GitHub responds with:

```
/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=[...]
```

I never want to access my GitLab instance with http-only. How do I force GitLab to report the `https://` url to GitHub without it handling HTTPS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @josch already gave the answer to his specific problem, I had another case of this error with a different solution.

When running a GitLab 7.7.2 ("from source") behind an Apache proxy, the same error occurred when attempting to authorize with my GitHub account, even though I used

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

in the site configuration.

The fix, as it turned out, was to set the OAuth `Authorization callback URL` protocol on GitHub to `http://` instead of `https://`, although the site is publicly available only over SSL.

[image: GitHub OAuth Authorization URL]

Comment: Thanks, I hit the problem again with gitlab 8.4.3 and my old fix doesn't seem to work anymore but yours does.

Comment: By the way, I eventually decided to run GitLab in docker instead and it works very well for me. The SSH clone urls do look a bit weird though due to the secondary SSH port used, but apart from that it's perfect. You might want to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around I found out that setting the following in the nginx config solves the issue:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
```

Since I always want to access my gitlab instance via https, this works well for me and seems to also make oauth possible now.

Sorry, I should've played around with this longer before posting this question but maybe this helps somebody else with the same problem.

Comment: I know it's against community rule to just thank someone in the comment, but I had to leave this thank you note. My team and I spent the last 7 hours trying to get a OAuth signature to match. We found out that the request URI was slightly different (http vs https) due to our reverse proxy, but didn't have a plan on how to change it. We even went into our 3rd party OAuth library to try and rewrite the signature generation. This simple switch (plus proxy_redirect) allowed us to solve the problem. Just 2 lines of config change. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A `gitlab-ctl tail` put me on the track. Here are the settings that worked for me:

In the application config in Github, I used the **exact same value** for

- *Homepage URL*
- and *Authorization callback URL*.

The value I used is `https://MY_GITLAB_FQDN/` (MY_GITLAB_FQDN being replaced by my actual hostname). Note the S in scheme HTTPS.

In my (external) nginx config, I already had the stanza

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

My config:

- Gitlab-CE 8.6.2, installed with Omnibus packages
- Ubuntu 14.04 server
- external nginx (thus nginx from `gitlab.rb` disabled)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was fixed by setting the `external_url` variable
with the `https` protocol in the url in the [omnibus config](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose)